# POSTGRESQL convert recursive function to loop function

Tags: postgresql, recursion

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employee(IN emp_id integer)

 RETURNS TABLE(id integer, name text, designation text, salary integer,   man_id integer) AS
$BODY$

BEGIN

RETURN QUERY

WITH recursive manager_hierarchy(e_id,e_name,e_desig,e_sal,m_id) AS

(
select e.id,e.name,e.designation,e.salary,e.man_id FROM emp_table e 
WHERE e.id=emp_id
union
SELECT
rp.id,rp.name,rp.designation,rp.salary,rp.man_id
FROM
manager_hierarchy mh
INNER JOIN emp_table rp ON mh.e_id=rp.man_id
)

SELECT h.e_id,h.e_name,h.e_desig,h.e_sal,h.m_id
FROM manager_hierarchy h;
END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

can anyone help me to change the same program with using loop

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: I this code there is no issue. But want to change this code with out using recursive function

Comment: this code is not having any issue. But i want the same code without using recusive function.

Comment: The _function_ itself is **not** recursive. You use a single query which in turn is a recursive common table expression. You can't get the same result without making the _function_ recursive.

Comment: @Nikhil It's not a "Write my code for me" place. If you have a problem writing the code show what you have tried and what the problem is, if you don't have a problem then hire someone or read the manuals and come back with a real problem.